# Multiple touch enabled CCLayers, top layer not consuming touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

I have 2 CCLayers stacked on top of each other; both are touch enabled. I want the top CCLayer to respond to and consume touches and the bottom layer to not react to the touches that the top layer consumes.

The top layer has a CCTouchBegan method that looks like this:

```
- (BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touched!");

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    //DO STUFF WITH TOUCH

    return YES;
}
```

The bottom layer has a CCTouchesEnded method that looks like this:

```
- (void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //choose one of the touches to work with
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    //DO STUFF WITH THE TOUCH
}
```

The result is that the top layer does not consume the touches or even respond to them at all. Only the bottom layer responds to the touches.

Comment: We need more information than this to answer your question. What are these layers containing? How are they being set up? Where are they being added to the screen?

Comment: @TheDanman does it matter which layer 'consumes' the touch?

Comment: if you use ccTouchBegan then you have to use ccTouchEnded (not ccTouchesEnded)

Comment: @jonathanlking Yes it does very much. This is the source of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your first layer you use method from CCTargetedTouchDelegate. CCLayer register self as CCStandardTouchDelegate. That's why your second layer responds to the touches.

Comment: Is there any way I can register the top CCLayer as a CCTargetedTouchDelegate?

Comment: use search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056222/touch-handled-by-two-layers